# How to imagine a process of generating theorems from a formal system in a computer?

Tags: computer-science, formal-systems

I'm aware that it is possible to create a formal system in a computer to generate theorems from it. How could I imagine such a system in a computer which generates theorems in a way that would be easily demonstrable for a student? Are you able to create an example of such a system for a person to grasp more easily how it operates in a computer?

Comment: "material way" ?

Comment: Consider e.g. [propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Generic_description_of_a_propositional_calculus).

Comment: See e.g. [Metamath](http://us.metamath.org/). Obviously, it is a computer program; see e.g. a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler).

Comment: If you are familiar with computer usage, by itself you have been "exposed" to the concept of *formal system*. Try use Excel : you can write string of symbols; some will be rejected as wrong. They are parsed by the system and rejected as "ungrammatical" i.e. not manufactured according to the rules of the syntax of the system.